# Padding 1x1 in MaxPooling Layer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

What is your interpretation of this following MaxPoolLayer padding?

MaxPool 3x3, stride 2x2 padding 1x1

does it mean that I pad my tensor with 1's ?

Comment: Please re-write your question and insert the actual TensorFlow code snippet. But it looks like you pad with zero, then do a max pooling with a 3x3 window and use stride of 2 in both horizontal and vertical dimension.

Comment: this is the description that I found in a paper. In tensorflow my current implementation would be something like: x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(x)

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation looks correct. The only catch is as [TensorFlow documents](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MaxPool2D) state for padding argument of `MaxPool2D`:

"One of "valid" or "same" (case-insensitive). "valid" adds no zero padding. "same" adds padding such that if the stride is 1, the output shape is the same as input shape."

So according to your stride and input, TF automatically decides how to pad your input. You could do something like this:

```
paddings = tf.constant([[1, 1,], [0, 0]])
input = tf.pad(input, paddings, "CONSTANT")
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='valid')(input)
```

To make sure 1x1 padding is applied all the time. For more information, take a look at [documents](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad)